# How to setup 404 or 500 error handlers with Redux Toolkit and RTKQuery

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using **RTKQuery** to fetch data as following:

```
export const productsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'productsApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
    prepareHeaders,
  }),
  tagTypes: ['Products'],
  keepUnusedDataFor: 8600,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getProperties: builder.query<IProduct[], IParams>({
      query: params => ({ url: 'products', params: { per_page: 40, ...params } }),
      transformResponse: ({ data }: { data: IProduct[] }) => data,
      providesTags: ['Products'],
    }),
  });
```

I am relatively new to Redux Toolkit and started it using directly before using any of Redux. From the ReduxToolkit documentation, I'm finding 2 ways to catch and put actions on the backend.

1. Using Async thunk.
2. Middleware

I tried using the code as follows with the Middleware approach:

```
export const rtkQueryErrorLogger: Middleware = (api: MiddlewareAPI) => next => action => {
  if (isRejected(action)) {
     console.log(action);
  }
  return next(action);
}
```

But this does not catch the 40x/50x errors. What should be the way to handle this?

The purpose is to say send logs to the server upon catching these errors with meta-information. I was following: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/error-handling#handling-errors-at-a-macro-level as a reference.

Comment: What exactly is your use case here? Generally, every endpoint will handle this and just switch into an "error" state.

Comment: I want a common method to send logs to the server and show a toast maybe to the end-user. @phry Can this be done using a middleware function like `rtkQueryErrorLogger`

Comment: That should be doable like in the link you gave there. Did you maybe forget to add that middleware to `configureStore`?

Comment: I did add that. But only cancelled rejected issues show up in the console and not the 404 errors.

Comment: Do those show up within RTK Query as errors? If not, did you maybe use a non-standard `baseQuery`?

Comment: I used `fetchBaseQuery` actually the one recommended in the docs. I just see issues for queries that were rejected because of caching and all. But no-404 errors

Comment: But in the devtools, you see these as rejected actions?

Answer (score 1):

More than a year later, I am looking into this. I think the middleware approach is ok, but you could also use a custom `baseQuery` for this.
Your specific case seems to have other things to debug as well, but you did not provide enough information for that.

I think that the documentation for RTKQuery is wrong: `isRejected` is a higher order function that require thunks as arguments. This applies also to other matchers as well, such as `isRejectedWithValue`.

I believe that, to check for any rejected action, your middleware should be like the following, even though this is not clearly documented.

```js
export const rtkQueryErrorLogger: Middleware = (api: MiddlewareAPI) => next => action => {
  if (isRejected()(action)) {
     console.log(action);
  }
  return next(action);
}
```

Remember of course also to **add the middleware to the store creator**.

---

See also the official documentation https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isrejected

> #### isRejected
>
> A higher-order function that returns a type guard function that may be
> used to check whether an action is a 'rejected' action creator from
> the createAsyncThunk promise lifecycle.
>
> ##### isRejected usage
>
> ```
> import { isRejected } from '@reduxjs/toolkit' import type { AnyAction
> } from '@reduxjs/toolkit' import { requestThunk1, requestThunk2 } from
> '@virtual/matchers'
>
> const isARejectedAction = isRejected(requestThunk1, requestThunk2)
>
> function handleRejectedAction(action: AnyAction) {   if
> (isARejectedAction(action)) {
>     // action is a rejected action dispatched by either `requestThunk1` or `requestThunk2`   } }
> ```